# How to fix "Uncaught DataManager - executeLocal() : A query is required to execute"

Tags: git, syncfusion

I have more than branch on git and all code was successfully running and no errors have been recorded,

When I merge those branches the following error occurs on developer tools:

`Uncaught DataManager - executeLocal() : A query is required to execute`

I've tried to delete the new branch and check out the 2 old branches, everything is fine, the error only occurs when I merge the 2 branches.

After I reload the page the error is gone. It's only on load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same situation with the `ej2-data` package and `ej2-angular-xxx` packages. This is caused because the types/instances mismatches.

I solved this by just removing all the non `ej2-angular-xxx` packages, and relying the `ej2-angular-xxx` to pick its dependencies.

I don't know if your issue is happening in Angular, but again, this same issue happened to me and was because of ambiguous versions and relied all the top libraries (`ej2-angular-xxx`) to pick their specific dependencies by themselves and rip them off from my `package.json`.